# Minimum Window Substring leetcode #76

Tags: java, string, hashmap, substring, sliding-window

Given two strings `s` and `t` of lengths `m` and `n` respectively, return *the **minimum window*** substring *of*`s`*such that every character in*`t`*(**including duplicates**) is included in the window*. If there is no such substring, return *the empty string*`""`.The testcases will be generated such that the answer is **unique**.

This is my code for it.

```
class Solution {
    public String minWindow(String s, String t) {
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<t.length();i++){
            map.put(t.charAt(i),map.getOrDefault(t.charAt(i),0)+1);
            count++;
        }
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int first = 0;
        int last = s.length()-1;
        for(;j<s.length();j++){
            if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(j))){
                if(map.get(s.charAt(j))>0){
                    count--;
                }
                map.put(s.charAt(j),map.get(s.charAt(j)-1));
            }
            while(count==0){
                first = i;
                last = j;
                if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
                    if(map.get(s.charAt(i))==0){
                        count--;
                    }
                    map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
                }                
                i++;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        for(int k=first;k<=last;k++){
            ans.append(s.charAt(k));
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}
```

```
The output shown is : 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.HashMap.get(Object)" is null
  at line 24, Solution.minWindow
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```